# Как работают предложенные правки?

Tags: поддержка, faq, предлагаемые-правки

После нажатия кнопки «править» на экране появляется сообщение:

> Ваша правка будет поставлена в очередь, пока не пройдёт экспертную проверку.
>
> Мы рады любым конструктивным правкам, но они должны быть существенными. Вносить несущественные правки разрешается только в случаях крайней необходимости.

Пример:

[image: Сообщение на сайте: У вас нет прав на редактирование. Ваша правка будет добавлена в очередь проверок и проверена другими пользователями.]

Также если, не авторизовавшись на сайте, нажать на ссылку «улучшить этот вопрос» или «улучшить этот ответ», на экране появляется сообщение:

> Вы не [вошли](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login). Ваша правка будет помещена в очередь до тех пор, пока она не пройдёт [экспертную проверку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).

Существует ли определенное минимальное значение репутации, достигнув которое можно вносить правки без автоматического утверждения? Как можно увидеть список неутвержденных правок на тех сайтах, на которых моя репутация позволяет вносить правки?

> Чтобы узнать больше о редактировании, прочтите материал «[Почему кто-то может редактировать мои сообщения? Как работает система редактирования?](/help/editing)» в [Справочном центре](/help).

<sub>Свободный перевод: [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

#### Кто может предлагать правки?

- Зарегистрированные участники, не имеющие [прав на редактирование](/privileges/edit) (имеющие менее 2000 баллов репутации), могут предлагать правки к любым сообщениям или описаниям меток.
- Зарегистрированные участники, [имеющие право на редактирование](/privileges/edit), но не являющиеся «[проверенными участниками](/help/privileges/trusted-user)» (имеющие от 2000 до 20000 баллов репутации), могут предлагать правки к описаниям меток.
- Анонимные пользователи могут предлагать правки к любым сообщениям, *опубликованным более [10 минут назад](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97221/dont-allow-suggested-edits-until-post-is-one-hour-old/97228#97228)*. Такие правки публикуются от имени [«Духа ♦ сообщества»](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) после их утверждения.

#### Куда попадают предложенные правки?

Предложенные правки попадают в очередь проверок, имеющую фиксированный размер. Если очередь проверок заполнена, вносить предложения о правках не разрешается до того момента, пока в очереди не появится свободное место.

#### Кто может голосовать за предложенные правки?

- Автор сообщения может имеет решающий голос в принятии или отклонении любого изменения, вносимого в его сообщение.
- Любой участник, [имеющий право вносить правки](/privileges/edit), может голосовать за предложенные правки к сообщениям.
- Участники, имеющие [5000 и более баллов репутации](/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), могут голосовать за предложенные правки к описаниям меток.
- Для удаления предложенной правки из очереди, то есть её принятия, либо отклонения, требуется два голоса.

#### Как принимаются предложенные правки?

Было бы здорово, чтобы большинство участников были вовлечены в процесс проверки, но имеется ряд ограничений:

- [ограничение](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77763/how-many-edits-can-i-approve-in-a-day) на количество голосов за принятие и отклонение правок в день.
- ограничение количества голосов, которое может отдать один участник за предложенные правки одним другим участником.

#### Могу ли я этим заработать себе баллы репутации?

- Если предложенная правка была принята, участник, предложивший ее, [получает](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/77505) 2 балла репутации. При этом за предложенные правки максимально за день можно заработать не более 1000 баллов репутации. Как и в других ситуациях, эти 2 балла репутации [аннулируются](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78147/do-you-lose-your-2-edit-rep-if-the-edited-post-is-subsequently-deleted/78154#78154) в случае, если редактируемое сообщение впоследствии [будет удалено](/a/5222/165773), однако, если предложенная правка отклонена, баллы репутации [не аннулируются](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected/78192#78192).
- После получения [привилегии редактирования](/privileges/edit) вносимые вами правки больше не подлежат проверке другими участниками. Вы больше не будете получаете баллы репутации за внесение правок.

#### Что насчет оскорбительных или «плохих» правок?

В отношении таких правок применяются строгие ограничения. Если участник (анонимный или зарегистрированный) вносит [слишком много правок, которые отклоняются сообществом](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/187824), ему автоматически устанавливается запрет на предложение правок [на срок в 7 дней](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/is-there-a-penalty-for-ones-edit-suggestion-being-rejected/78192#78192).

Установленный размер очереди проверок также помогает системе защититься от нежелательных правок.

#### Периодически [«Дух сообщества»](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) принимает или отклоняет мою правку. Что это означает?

«Дух сообщества» принимает или отклоняет вашу правку в одном из следующих случаев:

- один из участников, проверявших предложенную вами правку, нажал на кнопку «Улучшить» правку. В этом случае в зависимости от того, посчитал этот участник вашу правку полезной или нет, «Дух сообщества», соответственно, либо принимает, либо отклоняет эту правку. После оценки вашей правки «Духом сообщества» участник, проверявший ее, получает также возможность редактировать ее, что будет отражено в списке версий;
- вы предлагаете правку, и одновременно с вами это делает автор сообщения, участник с репутацией в 2000 или более баллов (для описаний меток — 20000 или более) или модератор (иными словами любой участник, имеющий права на редактирование данного сообщения). В этом случае предложенная вами правка будет отклонена «Духом сообщества» в пользу правки, внесенной участником, имеющим права на редактирование. Также на экране появится поясняющее сообщение «Ваша правка вступила в конфликт с другой правкой, внесенной одновременно с ней». *Не беспокойтесь!* За этим не последует наложение каких-либо запретов, в том числе на предложение правок. Просто попытайтесь еще раз отправить свою правку, чтобы она все-таки попала в очередь проверок.

В любом случае предложенные правки, которые были отклонены «Духом сообщества», не учитываются при наложении запрета на возможность предлагать правки. См. также http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992

#### Почему кнопка «править» заблокирована?

Система автоматически [приостанавливает возможность предлагать правки](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled/81701#81701) в некоторых случаях:

- за последние сутки большое количество предложенных вами правок было отклонено. На вас налагается запрет на неделю;
- очередь проверок заполнена;
- ранее в это сообщение уже была внесена правка, и она ожидает утверждения;
- вы не авторизовались, и сообщение было опубликовано менее 10 минут назад;
- ваша учетная запись временно заблокирована;
- сообщение было заблокировано;
- 5 предложенных вами правок ожидают утверждения.

В этих случаях кнопка «править» [блокируется](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91172/always-show-the-edit-button-on-questions/138944#138944), однако при наведении указателя мыши будет появляться всплывающее сообщение «Вы не можете предлагать правки».

#### Где можно увидеть все предложенные мною правки?

Вы можете просматривать список всех правок, когда-либо предложенных вами, в своей учетной записи, нажав на кнопку «все действия», расположенную во вкладке «Активность». Далее перейдите на страницу «предложения». Каждая строка списка включает в себя ссылку на предложенную правку, по которой можно перейти на нее, а также ссылку на редактируемое сообщение.

На странице предложенных правок вы сможете увидеть все голоса, за каждую из правок. В случае голоса против правки приводится причина отклонения (участники могут выбрать одну из стандартных причин, либо ввести свою причину). Обращайте особое внимание на причины отклонения правок, так как, зная их, впоследствии, вы сможете предлагать более качественные правки.

#### Как я узнаю о том, имеются ли правки, ожидающие проверки?

- В случае, если у вас есть права на редактирование сообщения, на экране появится кнопка "править (1)" вместо стандартной кнопки «править», когда вы переходите на страницу вопроса или ответа, имеющего непроверенные правки.
- Участники, имеющие более 2000 баллов репутации, получают уведомления [в верхней панели](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia0Gk.png) обо всех правках, ожидающих утверждения.
- Участники, имеющие более 10000 баллов репутации, имеют доступ к [истории предложенных правок](/review/suggested-edits/history) (участники с более низкой репутацией в данном случае видят историю только своих проверок).
- У модераторов есть доступ к дополнительному интерфейсу, который помогает им следить за текущим положением дел.

#### Применимо ли все это к описаниям меток?

**Да**, к описаниям меток также можно предлагать правки с учетом следующих ограничений:

- Участник, предлагающий правку, должен быть зарегистрирован.
- Предложенные правки к описаниям меток проверяются другими участниками в обычной очереди проверок, однако видны только тем из них, кто имеет не менее [5000 баллов репутации](/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).
- Участники, имеющие как минимум [20 тысяч баллов репутации](/privileges/trusted-user), обладают полными правами на редактирование описаний меток.

#### Для чего нужна кнопка «улучшить правку»?

Кнопка «улучшить правку» позволяет участникам сохранять изменения, внесенные в редактируемую версию текста, а также исправлять опечатки, сделанные автором правки, и вносить дополнительные изменения. Исправленный текст публикуется после того, как участник, который вносит исправления, сохранит изменения.

- В истории изменений предложенные правки и улучшенные правки определяются как отдельные события.
- Автор исходной правки также получает за нее 2 балла репутации.
- [«Дух сообщества»](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) несет ответственность за принятое решение. Таким образом, в разделе «Проверки» вкладки «Активность» в профиле участника, внесшего улучшения, не появляется никаких «утвержденных» элементов.

Кнопка «улучшить правку» доступна только тем участникам, у которых есть привилегии внесения правок напрямую без проверки другими участниками (20000 баллов репутации для внесения правок в описания меток на сайтах, прошедших аттестацию, и 4000 баллов — на сайтах на стадии открытой беты; в отношении всех других правок возможность выполнять проверки всегда соответствует правам, необходимым для улучшения правок).

#### Для чего нужна кнопка «отклонить и править»?

Нажатие этой кнопки приводит к отклонению предложенной правки и позволяет участнику, выполняющему проверку, сразу же перейти к улучшению нужной ему версии сообщения без учета правки. После сохранения внесенных изменений предложенная правка больше не может быть проверена.

- В историю изменений добавляются только улучшенные правки. Отклоненные предложенные правки не учитываются.
  – Исходный автор правки не получает за нее какие–либо баллы репутации.
  – [«Дух сообщества»](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) несет ответственность за принятое решение. Таким образом, в разделе «проверки» вкладки «активность» учетной записи участника, внесшего улучшения, не появляется никаких «отклоненных» элементов.

Кнопка «отклонить и править» доступна только участникам, у которых есть привилегии внесения правок напрямую без проверки другими участниками сообщества (20000 баллов репутации для внесения правок в описания меток на сайтах, прошедших аттестацию, и 4000 баллов — на сайтах в открытой бете; в отношении всех других правок возможность выполнять проверки всегда соответствует правам, необходимым для улучшения правок).

---

Обратите внимание на публикацию в блоге: «[Предложенные правки и их проверка](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/)».

Comment: А как же общие сообщения? И для меток же вроде ещё условия есть про рейтинг по самой редактируемой метке? И ограничение про не более 4К за все правки куда-то потерялось...

Comment: @Qwertiy Сделал общим! Пожалуйста, дополните публикацию!