# Почему авторы вопросов иногда отклоняют принятые правки их вопросов?

Tags: обсуждение, отклонённые-правки

Пример: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/169411), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/168572).
В обоих случаях правка была принята двумя участниками, а через некоторое время авторы вопроса отклоняли правку. С этими правками что-то не так?

Comment: [Присоединяюсь к вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/173675)

Comment: Вот ещё [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/697128/revisions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый пример надо было откатить - нельзя править чужой код, есть риск напортачить.
Второй - автор-самодур :)

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Казалось бы, в первом примере из изменений кода — только проставление пробелов и замена `math` на [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) в javascript коде, что вроде правильно.

Comment: Вот именно: вдруг проблема в `math` вместо `Math`? И пробелы лучше тоже не трогать, в пайтоне это вполне себе полноценные управляющие конструкции, тут не он, но лучше не лезть.

Comment: В javascript [точно-точно](https://jsfiddle.net/5b4ayped/) [нету](https://hsto.org/web/798/e95/007/798e95007ccf45bcbac77c9de7c6b3ab.png) math. Насчёт пробелов — там у него в одном месте они есть, в другом нету, наверняка лучше если в одном стиле будет?

Comment: Знаю что точно-точно нету. Аднака нет - пользовательский объект же! Приводить к единому стилю можно, но очень осторожно, зачастую лучше просто убрать/добавить отступы к блоку, не касаясь внутри.

Comment: Ладно-ладно... :)

Comment: Есть нюанс: стоит воздержаться от существенного улучшения кода в **вопросах**, т. к. легко внести исправление, касающееся сути вопроса, в результате чего вопрос потеряет смысл. Улучшать решения же очень даже стоит. Но не поперёк их авторам, конечно.

Comment: @D-side, тогда стоит написать комментарий,что и происходит зачастую.

Comment: @Aid, это ответ, а не вопрос. Теперь он поправил, после комментария.

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаемая правка должна содержать однозначно корректное улучшение. Уже есть несколько вопросов с обсуждением какие правки считать таковыми. Можете ознакомиться с ними:

- [Незначительные правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1951/176217)
- [Косметические правки. "вы -> Вы", "е -> ё"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3668/176217)
- [Отклонение правки, убирающей приветствия и благодарности](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4386/176217)

Общий механизм работы описан в вопросе [Как работают предложенные правки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5175/176217)

Я, кстати, тоже отклонил [Вашу правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/169402), предложенную на мой ответ. Объясняю почему:

- разворачивание `т.е.` и `т.к.` совершенно бессмысленно, это общеизвестные сокращения. К тому же, в последнем случае Вы оставили точку посредине предложения;
- стиль форматирования кода трогать в общем случае не стоит. Обычно он регламентируется корпоративными стандартами и у каждого может быть свой. Хотя, конечно, когда единого стиля не наблюдается вовсе или явно нарушено форматирование, правка может быть полезной. Но действовать надо очень аккуратно, и только в случае полной уверенности;
- замена `е` → `ё` (обсуждается в упомянутом ранее вопросе);
- замена `но при этом потеряем` → `а также`. Явное искажение смысла. Чёрное стало белым.

Есть конечно и корректные исправления с окончаниями, но на фоне перечисленных проблем они теряются. Поэтому правку проще отклонить.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки! Ту мою правку вы, конечно, правильно отклонили.